# Error: syntax error, unexpected 'else'

Tags: php

soy bastante nuevo en php y estoy desarrollando este codigo: Despues de investigar un poco no he podido descubrir porque el error continua. Lo que me gustaria que hiciese el codigo es que si se ha seleccionado ambas opciones del html vaya directamente a la segunda opcion del codigo. Pero en su lugar me muestra ambas tablas. Quizas sea algo sencillo, pero si me podeis ayudar estaria agradecido gracias.

No me dejan agregar el codigo entero pero dejo la parte del error y una imagen:

Agrego la parte del codigo que falla:

````
        Nombre de usuario:
        <input name="name" size="20" type="text" required /> </br></br>
        Contraseña:
        <input name="pass" size="20" type="password" /> </br></br>
        Base de datos:
        <input name="bd" size="20" required /> </br></br>

        <select name="seleccion">
        <option name="consultar1" value="1">Datos Cliente</option>

        </select>
        <p>
        <input type="radio" name="empleoactual" value="01"> Consultas ordenadas por Fecha<br>
        <input type="radio" name="empleoactual" value="02"> Consultas ordenadas por Nº de Cliente<br>
        <input type="radio" name="empleoactual" value="03"> Consultas ordenadas por Descripcion
        </p>
        <input value="Consultar" id="btm" type="submit">
        <input name='borrar' id="btm" type="reset" value="Borrar"></br></br>
    </form>

    <form action="datos.php" method='post'>
        <button name='regresar' id="btm">Cerrar Sesion</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php

    //conectar
    if(isset ($_POST['name']))
{
    $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['pass']=$_POST['pass'];
    $_SESSION['bd']=$_POST['bd'];

    $con=new mysqli ('localhost', $_POST['name'], $_POST['pass'], $_POST['bd']);
    $_SESSION['con']=$con;
    if($con->connect_error)
    {   die('No conectado Error N?:' .$con->connect_errno); }

    // para comprobar si se pulsa el boton

    if(isset($_POST['seleccion']) && $_POST['seleccion'] == 1)
    {
        //2 definir consulta sql y hacer la query
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        //3 mostrar datos en una tablas
        if($result->num_rows>0)
        {
?>
<html>
    <fieldset>
    <legend> Informacion personal del cliente y pedidos</legend>
    <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th>Nº Cliente</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellidos</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Tarjeta</th>
            <th>Correo</th>
            <th class="nuevo">Direccion</th>
            <th class="nuevo">Localidad</th>
            <th class="nuevo">Fecha</th>
            <th class="nuevo">Fecha Alta</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="text-align:center;">
    <?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['NumCliente'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['NombreC'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Apellidos'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Telefono'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Tarjeta'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Correo'] ?></td>
            <td class="nuevo"><?php echo $row['Direccion'] ?></td>
            <td class="nuevo"><?php echo $row['Localidad'] ?></td>
            <td class="nuevo"><?php echo $row['Fecha'] ?></td>
            <td class="nuevo"><?php echo $row['FechaA'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
</html>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    ```
<?php
    else (isset($_POST['seleccion']) && $_POST['seleccion'] == 01)
    {
        //2 definir consulta sql y hacer la query
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cliente` ORDER BY `cliente`.`Fecha` DESC";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        //3 mostrar datos en una tablas
        if($result->num_rows>0)
        {
?>
<html>
    <fieldset>
    <legend> Informacion personal del cliente y pedidos</legend>
    <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th>Nº Cliente</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellidos</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Tarjeta</th>
            <th>Correo</th>
            <th class="nuevo">Direccion</th>
            <th class="nuevo">Localidad</th>
            <th class="nuevo">Fecha</th>
            <th class="nuevo">Fecha Alta</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="text-align:center;">
    <?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['NumCliente'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['NombreC'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Apellidos'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Telefono'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Tarjeta'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Correo'] ?></td>
            <td class="nuevo"><?php echo $row['Direccion'] ?></td>
            <td class="nuevo"><?php echo $row['Localidad'] ?></td>
            <td class="nuevo"><?php echo $row['Fecha'] ?></td>
            <td class="nuevo"><?php echo $row['FechaA'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
</html>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
````

Comment: No pegues imágenes...

Comment: El último cierre de llaves está de más, al menos en esa sección de código que publicaste. Por otro lado, te recomiendo usar funciones o clases para organizar mejor y no redundar código. Si [indentas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentaci%C3%B3n) bien el código, esos errores son evitables fácilmente.

Comment: bueno estoy empezando, pero me gustaria que este funcionase antes de tocar algo mas.

Comment: Claro que te va a mostrar un error en el ELSE, le estas mandando una condicion en un else, deberia ser un ELSE IF> else if ((isset($_POST['seleccion']) && $_POST['seleccion'] == 01))...

Answer (score 0):

En tu código tienes éstas 2 condiciones, el error está en el else

```
if(isset($_POST['seleccion']) && $_POST['seleccion'] == 1)
else (isset($_POST['seleccion']) && $_POST['seleccion'] == 01)
```

Te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

```
if(isset($_POST['seleccion'])) {
    if($_POST['seleccion'] == 1) {
       // tu código
    }
    else {
       // tu código
    }
}
```

Tomar en cuenta de que éstas 2 condiciones son iguales, es decir que "1" es igual a "01".

```
 $_POST['seleccion'] == 1
 $_POST['seleccion'] == 01
```

Comment: Me seguia marcando error de que no esperaba ";". Despues de buscarlo lo corregi pero ahora no hace las consultas, solo se conecta a la base de datos y no muestra nada.

Comment: te recomiendo separar tu código para que no sea extenso.
Puedes optar por crear funciones o separar en diferentes archivos para que la revisión del código sea mucho mejor. 
Antes de mostrar los datos verificá tus datos imprimiendolo en un "print_r($datos); return;". Es bueno verificar, con calma todo se puede, saludos.